# React-admin custom routes

Tags: react-router, react-admin

I have a problem with the `CustomRoutes` component. I think I did everything as the documentation shows, but it's not working and I got a message

> [Route] is not a `<Route>` component. All component children of
> `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

What's the problem here?

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Admin, Resource, CustomRoutes } from 'react-admin';
import fetchData from './dataProvider.js'
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage.jsx'
import LogoutButton from './components/Common/LogoutButton.jsx'
import GroupsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Groups';
import hungarianMessages from 'ra-language-hungarian'
import polyglotI18nProvider from 'ra-i18n-polyglot'
import authProvider from './authProvider.js'
import Menu from './components/Common/Menu'
import theme from './theme.js'
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

...

import Settings from './pages/Settings.jsx'

import '@fontsource/asap'
import '@fontsource/roboto'

const i18nProvider = polyglotI18nProvider(() => hungarianMessages, 'hu', { allowMissing: true })

const dataProvider = fetchData()
const App = () => (
  
  <Admin
    theme={theme}
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
    menu={Menu}
    locale="hu"
    i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
    title={'Wallet'}
    loginPage={LoginPage}
    logoutButton={LogoutButton}
    authProvider={authProvider}
  >    
    <CustomRoutes>
      <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />            
    </CustomRoutes>
    <Resource
      name="partners"
      list={PartnerList}
      icon={GroupsIcon}
      edit={EditPartners}
      show={ShowPartner}
      create={CreatePartner}
    />
    ...
  </Admin>
)

export default App
```

Comment: Your code seems correct. Is it possible that you have installed another version of react-router-dom than the one from react-admin? Check your yarn.lock to see if there is more than one react-router-dom installation.

Comment: For step one it was good. it wasn't even installed..., but now I have more error messages with useLocation which I'm not even use, and useNavigate which I did like the example of the documentation. So it's a good first step to the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Add a CustomRoutes prop in the Admin tag rather than a CustomRoutes tag.

```
const routes = [
    <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings} />,
];
 <Admin
    customRoutes={routes}
    theme={theme}
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
    menu={Menu}
    locale="hu"
    i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
    title={'Wallet'}
    loginPage={LoginPage}
    logoutButton={LogoutButton}
    authProvider={authProvider}
  >
   <Resource /> 
</Admin>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `customRoutes` is deprecated from version 4.0.0